# Odd APPCRASH error in GCD program?

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
int GCD(int a, int b){
    while(b!=0){
        int temp=b;
        b=a%b;
        a=temp;
    }
    return a;
}
int main(){
    int a=0, b=0;
    cout<<"Please enter two integers to find their GCD using the Euclidean algorithm.";
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<"The greatest common divisor of "<<a<<" and "<<b<<" is "<<GCD(a,b)<<".";
}
```

This is a simple C++ program that finds the greatest common divisor of two numbers, and it runs just fine. However, if I change

```
int GCD(int a, int b){
    while(b!=0){
```

into `while(a!=0){`, I experience an APPCRASH error, exception code c0000094 that kills my run. I am running C++11 ISO standards and my IDE is Code::Blocks 16.

Comment: *I experience an APPCRASH error.* With what inputs?May be when `b=0`?

Comment: @MichaelWalz What if `b=0`?

Comment: @GauravSehgal Sorry for not clarifying, I used 100 and 150, 150 and 150, as well as 150 and 100. This was a simple assignment for an entry-level C++ course, so I disregarded exceptions (as well as how unprofessional that is :P)

Comment: @NamelessKing At some point inside `while(a!=0)` `b` will become `0` and you will be dividing by zero.See @Michael's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have a "division by 0" error.

Demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int GCD(int a, int b) {
  while (a != 0) {
    int temp = b;

    if (b == 0)
    {
      cout << "Divison by 0\n";
      return 0;
    }

    b = a % b;
    a = temp;
  }
  return a;
}

int main() {
  int a = 0, b = 0;
  cout << "Please enter two integers to find their GCD using the Euclidean algorithm.";
  cin >> a >> b;
  cout << "The greatest common divisor of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << GCD(a, b) << ".";
}
```

Input:

```
5
5
```

**Disclaimer**: this program only demonstrates that there is a "division by 0" error, it is still not correct.